# Suppose block matrix $D$ in $\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C&D\\ \end{pmatrix}$ has Schur complement $S$. Is $S^{-1}-A^{-1}$ positive semi-definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, positive-semidefinite

Suppose that the positive semi-definite matrix $M$ is partitioned into four submatrices
blocks as
$$M = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C&D\\ \end{pmatrix}$$
and block matrix $D$ has Schur complement
$$S = A-BD^{-1}C$$
I'm interested in the difference between $S^{-1}$ and $A^{-1}$. Is $S^{-1}-A^{-1}$ positive semi-definite? Or negative semi-definite? Or neither?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: Below, I am writing $A \succeq B$ for the Loewner order, meaning that
$$
A \succeq B \Leftrightarrow A - B \;\; \text{is positive semidefinite}.
$$

---

Since $M$ is positive semidefinite, we have
$$
M = M^T \Leftrightarrow
A = A^T, B = C^T, D = D^T.
$$

Therefore the difference you are interested in is
$$
(A - C^T D^{-1} C)^{-1} - A^{-1}.
$$

Using this, we can prove the following claim:

> **Claim**: The matrix $A - C^T D^{-1} C \preceq A$.

Finally, we use the fact that $A_1 \preceq A_2 \implies A_1^{-1} \succeq A_2^{-1}$ to deduce that the difference is PSD.

---

**Proof of Claim**: Note that
$$
A - C^T D^{-1} C \preceq A \Leftrightarrow
C^T D^{-1} C \succeq 0.
$$
Indeed, since $M$ is PSD, so is $D$ (and thus $D^{-1}$), which yields
$$
\langle x, C^T D^{-1} C x\rangle = \langle Cx, D^{-1} Cx\rangle \geq 0,
\quad \forall x.
$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on what $\succeq$ or ($\preceq$) stands for?

Comment: @Adrian I updated my response.

Comment: This question goes against [our quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.